# Synology SSH Root password does not work

Tags: linux, ssh, login, synology

Last night my Synology upgraded to a new version and now my Root password when logging in to SSH no longer works. I have already tested and I can login to other SSH accounts and I can also login to the Synology Admin Page (using same password that I am using for root).

Is there any reason why this would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found [this](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/6.0beta/ReleaseNote) webpage for one of the DSM6 Changelogs that says:

> Root account is replaced by administrators group credentials to log into SSH to enhance security.

To reset my root password, I just had to run:

```
synouser --setpw root [PASSWORD]
```

and this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

An updated, easier approach from [Synology's DSM help](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_login_to_DSM_with_root_permission_via_SSH_Telnet)

> SSH/Telnet only supports logging into the system with accounts belonging to the administrators group. **To switch to a root account**, please log into the system with SSH/Telnet as a user belonging to the administrators group, run the command **sudo -i**, and then enter the password of the account used to log in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this worked for me but only after I used PuTTY to login as admin and then access sudo by typing in PuTTY the command sudo ls, enter your admin password again when asked, and the issuing the command below.

sudo synouser -–setpw root [PASSWORD]

where [PASSWORD] MUST be the same as your admin password.

Now you can use WinSCP like you did before (DSM 5)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just SSH using rsa keys, then you can SSH as root, even after installing DSM6, without making any additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Method**

Using the DSM, use task scheduler app and run the following command, ensure you use 'root' user as runas in the drop down box: `synouser --setpw admin [PASSWORD]`

Then try to SSH in using `ssh admin@IP-ADDRESS`